# Xamarin Android Get Phone Number from Specific Contact

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, phone-number

I've been searching around for quite some time now and haven't found a working solution. I'd like to get the Phone Number from a specific Contact. The User can type in the Name of the Contact and click on Call to call the Contact, but I can't get the Phone Number. I hope someone can help me!

What I've tried so far:

```
public string result;
    private Intent pickContactIntent;
    public void pickContact()
    {
        pickContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick, ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri);
        pickContactIntent.SetType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentType);
        StartActivityForResult(pickContactIntent, 0);
    }

    protected void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode == 1)
        {
            if(resultCode == (int)Result.Ok)
            {
                result = data.GetType().ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CONTACT) {
    Uri contactsURI = data.getData();

    String[] queryFields = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };


    //Perform your query - the contactURI is like a "where"
    //clause here
    Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contactsURI, queryFields, null, null, null);


    //Double-check that you actually got results
    if (c.getCount() == 0) {
        c.close();
        return;
    }
    contactID = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    //Pull out the first column of the first row of data
    //that is your suspects name
    c.moveToFirst();

    String suspect = c.getString(0);


    mCrime.setmSuspect(suspect);
    mSuspectButton.setText(suspect);
    c.close();

}
```

Comment: See also http://www.morganskinner.com/2015/01/xamarin-forms-contacts-search.html

Comment: So what have you tried so far ?

Comment: But this is Xamarin.Forms and not Xamarin.Android

Comment: Added what I've already tried, it's not everything, because I couldn't find all I've tried. @Kaj